# How to create a function that only accepts int32 or int64

Tags: f#

How do I define a function in F# `f` that only accepts an argument `x` which is restricted to be of type `int32` or `int64` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way is to restrict it at compile time. First create the generic version of your function:

```
let inline twice x = x + x
```

Then restrict it for the desired types by using overload resolution and static member constraints:

```
type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, x:int  ) = twice x
    static member ($) (T, x:int64) = twice x

let inline restrictedTwice x = T $ x
```

Tests:

```
restrictedTwice 4  //val it : int = 8

restrictedTwice 5L //val it : int64 = 10L

restrictedTwice 5u // doesn't compile
```

Comment: This is a very powerful technique, but keep in mind it may drastically slow down compilation. https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/343

Answer (score 4):

## Overloading

If you can live with defining the function as a class method, you can use normal .NET method overloading:

```
type Foo =
    static member Bar (x : int)   = sprintf "32-bit integer: %i" x
    static member Bar (x : int64) = sprintf "64-bit integer: %i" x
```

FSI examples:

```
> Foo.Bar 42;;
val it : string = "32-bit integer: 42"
> Foo.Bar 42L;;
val it : string = "64-bit integer: 42"
```

## Discriminated unions

If you need the function to be a let-bound function, you can't use method overloading. [Instead, you can define a discriminated union](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions) that constrains the input options to either `int` or `int64`:

```
type DUInt =
| NormalInt of int
| BiggerInt of int64
```

You should probably come up with some better names, but I chose to avoid `Int32` and `Int64` because it would make the code difficult to read, as the `System` namespace also defines these names as *types*.

With this discriminated union, you can write a function that take a value of that type as input:

```
let foo = function
    | NormalInt x -> sprintf "32-bit integer: %i" x
    | BiggerInt x -> sprintf "64-bit integer: %i" x
```

This function has the type `DUInt -> string`.

FSI examples:

```
> foo (NormalInt 42);;
val it : string = "32-bit integer: 42"
> foo (BiggerInt 42L);;
val it : string = "64-bit integer: 42"
```

Comment: I'd like the function not to be a class member, and I'd like not to use discriminatedunion

Comment: @CarloV.Dango Worth putting into your question - perhaps explain a bit more about the intended consumption scenario and/or the nature of where you're exposing it

Comment: @RubenBartelink I thought the word 'function' implied that I was not creating methods ;)

Comment: Yes, you are technically correct and the question has no fluff. However the fact is that the simple answer to the simple question is "No, F# doesnt have direct support for that, which doesnt help anyone". Outlining parameters of potential variability within your context will enable people to be more creative in their answers (in this case, there was a trick you found palatable, but there may be usage scenarios not very far from yours where this technique is not applicable)

Comment: @rubenbartelink which situations is this technique not applicable?

Comment: @CarloV.Dango The accepted answer varies the function not only on input type, but also on *return* type. This is apparently what's preferred here (that's fine), but in other cases, one may need a function that can deal with disparate input, but always return the same type of result. [Here's an example of this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions).